# Como unifico linhas de um Pandas DataFrame que variam em apenas alguns campos?

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um DataFrame com o seguinte formato:

[image: formato do dataframe original]

E gostaria de ter o seguinte resultado:

[image: formato do dataframe que preciso obter]

Como faço pra conseguir isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente com esse código:

```
df = pd.read_excel('companies.xlsx')  # seu arquivo de input

cnpjs = df['cnpj'].unique()
aggregator = []

for cnpj in cnpjs: 
    company_df = df.loc[df['cnpj'] == cnpj] 
    for index, socio in enumerate(company_df['socio'], 1): 
        company_df.loc[:, 'socio_' + str(index)] = socio 
        company_df = company_df.drop(columns='socio') 
   aggregator.append(company_df)

result = pd.concat(aggregator, sort=False)
result = result.drop_duplicates(subset=['cnpj', 'empresa', 'endereco', 'telefone'])
result.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(result)
```

Input:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a linha `company_df.loc[:, 'socio_' + str(index)] = socio` resulta em um `SettingWithCopyWarning`, mas acredito que este pode ser ignorado sem maiores consequências, já que estamos usando o operador `df.loc` para acessar e modificar subslices de DataFrames, conforme a recomendação oficial do Pandas.